# Oracle 19c compatibility with jdk7

Tags: java, database, oracle, driver, java-7

I would like to know if oracle 19c is compatible with jdk 7.

I have found out 2 drivers for oracle 19c

- ojdbc8 : for jdk8, jdk9 and jdk11
- ojdbc10 : for jdk10 and jdk11

I would like to know if there is a way to have oracle 19c with a jdk7, and if yes what is the driver that will allow to do it ?

Comment: What errors do you get when you try this?

Comment: Java 7 reached End of Life five years ago, I would be very surprised if Oracle have invested any time at all in building driver support for it.

Comment: @BobJarvis-ReinstateMonica   Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: oracle/jdbc/OracleDriver : Unsupported major.minor version 54.0 (unable to load class oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver)

Comment: You can try to use the JDBC driver for Oracle 11.2.0.4 which is still available on the Oracle download page and can be used with Java 7.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the [Oracle JDBC FAQ](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/faq-jdbc.html) (Question "What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?"), only the Java versions you listed (Java 8 to 11) are supported for Oracle 19c.

- I expect that support for later Java versions will be added in the future.
- Java 9 and Java 10 were short-life releases, and are both end-of-life.

As a comment notes, Java 7 has been "end of life" since April 2015.  It would be counter-productive for Oracle to encourage continued use of Java 7 by supporting it with new JDBC drivers for new Oracle database releases.

Note that the Oracle drivers are proprietary and source code is not available.  So back-porting one of the Oracle 19c compatible drivers to Java 7 is not an option.

You may be able to identify a 3rd-party vendor who will provide (probably sell) you a driver that works.  The best I could come up with is this *old* page that lists vendors:

- https://www.mindprod.com/jgloss/jdbcvendors.html

---

**In summary**: If you want to use Oracle 19c with Oracle supported drivers, upgrading to Java 8 LTS *or later* is the only feasible solution.  Upgrading to Java 11 LTS is advisable:

- Oracle Java 8 LTS free public updates (for commercial users) have ended, and Premium Support is due to end in March 2022; see the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-se-support-roadmap.html).
- You can still get free public Java 8 LTS updates from 3rd-party vendors post 2020; see [Java is Still Free](https://medium.com/@javachampions/java-is-still-free-2-0-0-6b9aa8d6d244) for all of the details.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm the the **ojdbc7.jar** running on a **JDK 7** will work connecting to an **Oracle 19C** server.

Looking at the Oracle JDBC FAQ it does not look like this is officially supported, however we have a current client in the process of upgrading their JDK, but we needed to support JDK 7 in the short term.

Our Oracle server was an AWS RDS instance, previously running **Oracle 12C**, but Amazon is no longer supporting this, and we were forced to upgrade to **Oracle 19c**.

We had some JDK 8 environments (container JBoss 7) which were already using **ojdbc7.jar** and these were fine. The JDK 7 environment (container JBoss 5.2) were using **ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar** and was failing with exception:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-28040: No matching
> authentication protocol
>
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:439)    at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:388)     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:381)     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.processError(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:427)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:436)     at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)    at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoauthenticate.doOSESSKEY(T4CTTIoauthenticate.java:390)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.logon(T4CConnection.java:356)   at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.(PhysicalConnection.java:531)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.(T4CConnection.java:221)
> at
> oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CDriverExtension.getConnection(T4CDriverExtension.java:32)
> at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver.connect(OracleDriver.java:503)   at
> org.jboss.resource.adapter.jdbc.local.LocalManagedConnectionFactory.getLocalManagedConnection(LocalManagedConnectionFactory.java:207

After switching from **ojdbc6-11.2.0.1.0.jar** to: **ojdbc7.jar** the application functioned normally.

Just a caveat, I quickly tested our application read/writing to the DB, and these worked as expected, your mileage may vary, as mentioned above this is not officially supported.