# Hibernate Dialect 10g for Oracle Database 19C

Tags: hibernate, oracle10g, oracle12c, oracle19c

I'm using hibernate which is 3.2.4 and having Oracle 12C DB with Oracle10gDialect. Now am thinking to upgrade Oracle DB to Oracle 19C.

**For Upgrading to 19c, whether "*org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect*" will be supported along with hibernate-3.2.4?**

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60229498/618465), you will need Java 8+ to use Oracle 19c.

Hibernate 3.2.4 is very old and likely does not support Java 8+, [Hibernate 5.0 only supports Java 5,6,7](https://hibernate.org/orm/releases/5.0/).

To upgrade to Oracle 19c, you will need to upgrade Hibernate to version 5.4+ beforehand.