# Oracle19c with AIX server, JDK7

Tags: websphere, oracle12c, java-7, aix, oracle19c

Our application is using JDK7, websphere and is hosted on AIX box.
Recently we upgraded to oracle 19c from 12c. After this, application server does not start.
We do not see any error in startup logs. All application modules do not load, hence server does not come up.

We tried commenting all unnecessary modules in ILSStartupDef.xml, but same issue.
JDBC jar that we are using is ojdbc7-12.1.0.2.0-p0.jar.
Can someone please help ? Any config changes that we may be missing ? We dont want to upgrade to java8 unless its absolutely necessary.

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/224217/safe-to-use-sqlnet-allowed-logon-version-server-in-11g-sqlnet-ora-file/224222#224222

Comment: You mean your application is an Oracle _client,_ and you have updated your Oracle _server?_

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Can you confirm that the database connexion test on the console is working properly ?

Note : Upgrading to Java 8 can be challenging, but Java 7 is no more supported.

Based on this document from IBM :
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/websphere-application-server-support-policy-jdbc-databases-and-drivers

That being said, yes we do support Oracle 18C and 19C in WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.X and V9.0.x but you must aware of this following.

1. We dont test WebSphere Application Server with each and every release of Oracle database. Please make sure you do the test before moving to production.
2. **I believe the oracle 18C or later driver supports java 8 or later release only, if so please make sure WAS java level is also java 8. Java 8 is supported in 8.5.5.9 or later release.**
3. If you ever see this issue, please consider upgrading WAS and do the test again. This issue is fixed in 8.5.5.13 or later release.
   Good Luck

From Oracle perspective, please check this post :
[Oracle 19c compatibility with jdk7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60229135/oracle-19c-compatibility-with-jdk7)

According to the Oracle JDBC FAQ (Question "What are the Oracle JDBC releases Vs JDK versions?"), only the Java versions you listed (Java 8 to 11) are supported for Oracle 19c.

I would advise to do the assessment for migrating to Java 8, using Transformation Advisor.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

If you have upgraded the database server version to 19c then, it is recommended to upgrade the JDBC driver to the same version. So, you should use [19c JDBC driver](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/jdbc-downloads.html).

19c JDBC driver requires JDK8 or JDK11. So, it is time to upgrade the JDK version as well as the JDBC driver as well.